# Use store values in ngrx/data

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using ngrx/data and what I need to do is set a value in the store, let's call this ID. And then when I make any request to an entity to pull that ID from the store. I will use `update` as an example.

Here is an example of a Client Entity Service. I can easily map the returned data as `super.update` returns an observable.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityCollectionServiceBase, EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory } from '@ngrx/data';
import { Client } from '../../store/client/client.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientEntityService extends EntityCollectionServiceBase<Client> {

  constructor(
    serviceElementsFactory: EntityCollectionServiceElementsFactory,
  ) {
    super('Client', serviceElementsFactory);
  }

  public update(entity: Partial<Client>): Observable<Client> {
    return super.update(entity);
  }

}
```

However I want to use a store value to make the update. So focusing on the `update` I can do this:

```
public update(entity: Partial<Client>): Observable<Client> {
    this.store.pipe(
      tap((store) => {
        console.log(store);
      })
    ).subscribe();
    return super.update(entity);
  }
```

Which prints out the store and I can see the value I need, so I could do this

```
public update(update: Partial<Client>): Observable<Client> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getClientId),
      take(1)
    ).subscribe((id) => {
      return super.update({
        id,
        ...update
      });
    });
  }
```

However it is requiring me to subscribe to the observable to be able to trigger it. That would mean the caller could not pipe the results and is generally not ideal.

I am wondering if anyone knows of a good solution to be able to get the data from the store but not have to subscribe like I am doing above to get the data, ideally I would want to use a `switchMap` like this:

```
  public update(update: Partial<Client>): Observable<Client> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getClientId),
      switchMap((id) => {
        return super.update({
          id,
          ...update
        });
      }),
      take(1)
    )
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You wrote it correctly in your ideal solution. The difference is that you just need to move take(1) to be right after the select.

```js
public update(update: Partial<Client>): Observable<Client> {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select(getClientId),
      take(1),
      switchMap((id) => {
        return super.update({
          id,
          ...update
        });
      }),
    )
```

so store won't cause `update` requests on every change.

Answer (score 0):

After stepping into the `super.update` call I could see that the dispatcher was calling:

```
update(entity, options) {
        // update entity might be a partial of T but must at least have its key.
        // pass the Update<T> structure as the payload
        /** @type {?} */
        const update = this.toUpdate(entity);
        options = this.setSaveEntityActionOptions(options, this.defaultDispatcherOptions.optimisticUpdate);
        /** @type {?} */
        const action = this.createEntityAction(EntityOp.SAVE_UPDATE_ONE, update, options);
        if (options.isOptimistic) {
            this.guard.mustBeUpdate(action);
        }
        this.dispatch(action);
        return this.getResponseData$(options.correlationId).pipe(
        // Use the update entity data id to get the entity from the collection
        // as might be different from the entity returned from the server
        // because the id changed or there are unsaved changes.
        map((/**
         * @param {?} updateData
         * @return {?}
         */
        updateData => updateData.changes)), withLatestFrom(this.entityCollection$), map((/**
         * @param {?} __0
         * @return {?}
         */
        ([e, collection]) => (/** @type {?} */ (collection.entities[this.selectId((/** @type {?} */ (e)))])))), shareReplay(1));
    }
```

Which effectively just dispatches some actions and then creates a selected observable from `this.getResponseData$` using the correlationid etc.

In my use case because I am using the store to get the Id of the current client I don't need the updated client returned as I already have an observable.

On top of the `ClientEntityService` I have another facade which I am calling `ClientService`.

Which looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ClientService {
  constructor(
    private clientEntityService: ClientEntityService,
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {}

  public getCurrentClient(): Observable<Client> {
    return this.clientEntityService.entityMap$.pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getCurrentId))),
      map(([clients, currentId]) => clients[currentId])
    );
  }

  public updateCurrentClient(update: Partial<Client>): Subscription {
    return this.getCurrentClient().pipe(
      take(1),
      switchMap((client) => {
        return this.clientEntityService.update({
          id: client.id,
          ...update
        });
      })
    ).subscribe();

  }
}
```

So now from within my component I have the constructor

```
constructor(
    private clientService: ClientService,
  ) {
    this.client$ = this.clientService.getCurrentClient();
  }
```

And then on update I call:

```
this.clientService.updateCurrentClient(theUpdate);
```

And because I already have `this.client$` as an observable of that client being updated I don't need `updateCurrentClient` to return `Observable<Client>`. So as per above I am just returning `Subscription`

I *could* modify `updateCurrentClient` to implement something similar to what the DefaultDataService returns, but I'd expect that could be subject to change in future versions. So for now. I am happy with this solution.